# What is a terrible failure with my mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, null

I wrote trigger that contains the following lines:

```
DECLARE is_journal TINYINT(1);
SET @is_journal := 1;

IF (is_journal IS NOT NULL) THEN 
        INSERT INTO `log` VALUES("is_journal is not null");
ELSE
        INSERT INTO `log` VALUES("is_journal is null");
END IF;
```

And in my `log` table I always get as result

> is_journal is null

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are setting value to **`@is_journal`**. And comparing value of  **`is_journal`**.

So first of all you have knowledge that both this thing are different.

So instead of

**`IF (is_journal IS NOT NULL) THEN`**  line put

**`IF (@is_journal IS NOT NULL) THEN`** .

Comment: Thank you, it's my inadvertence)